# why is the optimizer not allowed to fold in "constant context"?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++20

`__builtin_is_constant_evaluated` is the builtin used to for implementing `std::is_constant_evaluated` in the standard library on clang and gcc.

code that is not valid in constant context is also often harder for the optimizer to constant fold.

for example:

```
int f(int i) {
    if (__builtin_is_constant_evaluated())
        return 1;
    else {
        int* ptr = new int(1);
        int i = *ptr;
        delete ptr;
        return i;
    }
}
```

is emitted by `gcc -O3` as:

```
f(int):
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 4
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     esi, 4
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
        mov     eax, 1
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

so the optimizer used `__builtin_is_constant_evaluated() == 0`

clang fold this to a constant but this is because clang's optimizer can remove unneeded dynamic allocation, not because it used `__builtin_is_constant_evaluated() == 1`.

i am aware that this would make the return value of `__builtin_is_constant_evaluated()` implementation defined because optimization vary from one compiler to an other. but is_constant_evaluated should already be used only when both path have the same observable behaviors.

why does the optimizer not use `__builtin_is_constant_evaluated() == 1` and fallback to `__builtin_is_constant_evaluated() == 0` if it wasn't able to fold ?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for something like [following](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Miw702)

Comment: First of all, I'm not certain of what I say, so I'm just posting this as a comment. Your function is not `constexpr` so `__builtin_is_constant_evaluated()` will always be false. I'm not an expert at all on how compilers work internally, but I think that even if you add `constexpr` they won't emit the branch for constant evaluation. For example, if you add this line `constexpr int i = f(4)`, the final program will not even call `f()` to initialize `i`, `f(4)` will just be replaced by its result. So the final program do not need this branch, it only needs the one for runtime evaluation.

Comment: 1. If the false branch of `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())` is slower, then why bother writing the condition at all? 2. There are cases between "able to fold" and "not able to fold" (i.e. "able to partially fold").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [[meta.const.eval]](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.const.eval):

> ```
> constexpr bool is_constant_evaluated() noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `true` if and only if evaluation of the call occurs within the evaluation of an expression or conversion that is manifestly
>   constant-evaluated ([expr.const]).

`f` can never be invoked in a constant-evaluated expression or conversion, so `std::is_constant_evaluated()` returns `false`.  This is decided by the compiler and has nothing to do with the optimizer.

Of course, if the optimizer can prove that the branches are equivalent, it can do constant fold.  But that is *optimization* after all — beyond the scope of the C++ language itself.

But why is it this way?  The proposal that introduced `std::is_constant_evaluated` is [P0595](https://wg21.link/p0595).  It explains the idea well:

> ```
> constexpr double power(double b, int x) {
>   if (std::is_constant_evaluated() && x >= 0) {
>     // A constant-evaluation context: Use a
>     // constexpr-friendly algorithm.
>     double r = 1.0, p = b;
>     unsigned u = (unsigned)x;
>     while (u != 0) {
>       if (u & 1) r *= p;
>       u /= 2;
>       p *= p;
>     }
>     return r;
>   } else {
>     // Let the code generator figure it out.
>     return std::pow(b, (double)x);
>   }
> }
>
> // ...
> double thousand() {
>   return power(10.0, 3);  // (3)
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Call (3) is a core constant expression, but an implementation is not
>   required to evaluate it at compile time. We therefore specify that it
>   causes `std::is_constant_evaluated()` to produce `false`. It's
>   tempting to leave it unspecified whether `true` or `false` is produced
>   in that case, but that raises significant semantic concerns: The
>   answer could then become inconsistent across various stages of the
>   compilation. For example:
>
> ```
> int *p, *invalid;
> constexpr bool is_valid() {
>   return std::is_constant_evaluated() ? true : p != invalid;
> }
> constexpr int get() { return is_valid() ? *p : abort(); }
> ```
>
> This example tries to count on the fact that constexpr evaluation
>   detects undefined behavior to avoid the non-constexpr-friendly call to
>   `abort()` at compile time. However, if `std::is_constant_evaluated()`
>   can return `true`, we now end up with a situation where an important
>   run-time check is by-passed.

Comment: i understand how it works but i don't understand why it works this way.

Comment: @Tyker I have updated my answer to address your comment.